# AlarmManager never runs

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm very inexperienced with Android and having trouble trying to get an `AlarmManager` to basically run a small activity that spawns a notification every hour (for testing purposes I lowered it to every 10 seconds.

However it doesn't seem like the activity gets called at all. Logcat shows nothing and no `Toast` appears, let alone notifications being created.

`Context` may be the issue, I didn't entirely understand what I was meant to be passing there so I might have made a mistake by passing in `MainActivity.this` but I couldn't figure out what would be more appropriate when I tried to Google it.

This code is contained in my `MainActivity`'s `OnCreate` method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        task = enterTask.getText().toString();
        if (!task.equals("Enter task here...") &&
                !task.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Saved task " + task,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("Current_Task", task);
            editor.commit();

            Context context = MainActivity.this;
            AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
            PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

            mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                    //AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
                    10000,
                    pi);
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my `Notify` activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Notifying",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    try {
        task = prefs.getString("Current_Task", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!task.equals("")){
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Current task")
                .setContentText("Hey! Have you " + task + "?");

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for testing purposes I lowered it to every 10 seconds

Note that depending on your Android version, it may not occur that frequently. Starting with Android 5.1, the minimum period is one minute.

> However it doesn't seem like the activity gets called at all.

Starting an activity periodically via `AlarmManager` is akin to shooting your users in the face with a shotgun: yes, it gets their attention, but not a very nice way.

In fact, your code to set up the alarms has it right: you are using `getBroadcast()` for the `PendingIntent`. This will trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`, not an `Activity`. Using a `BroadcastReceiver` is a far better solution for raising your `Notification`, as the `BroadcastReceiver` itself does not have any UI and therefore will not interrupt the user by taking over the foreground.

I recommend that you set up a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` and put your code from `onCreate()` (from the preferences onwards) into `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

If you *really* want to start an activity periodically, and you don't mind your users threatening to do unfortunate things to you, use `getActivity()` instead of `getBroadcast()` when creating your `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Ah, I did think Activities would be a heavy way to run at regular intervals. Thanks! Also about the minute minimum, would a lower value automatically be increased to a minute or would it invalidate the entire AlarmManager?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: "would a lower value automatically be increased to a minute" -- yes. There's a warning or something about it that gets logged to LogCat. Otherwise, it's just quietly raised to 60000ms.